# Trying to create a package in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, package

I am fairly new to programing but I am trying to create a new package in Eclipse and it is telling me that I already have the package created. Note: Views might filter empty parent packages. What does this mean? How do I fix it?

I have tried updating Maven project and changing to package view.

Comment: A new Java package or what kind of package you are talking about? In which view are you not able to see the package? Are you aware of _Help > Help Contents_?

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't have to create a Package before creating a Type inside it. The IDE knows where to correctly place the new source file and which parent directories need to be made on disk for it.

When it says "Views might filter empty parent packages", it literally means that the Package Explorer or Project Explorer in your perspective might be set to filter those out. The three vertical dots in the corner of the View's pane are for a local menu, specific to that View. Filters,  controls over what content is shown, and possibly how it's presented, would be accessible there.

Regardless, this won't be an issue once you actually put a type (Class or Interface) into your package. Those aren't hidden by default, and rarely intentionally by anyone.

Comment: So this is for a class I am taking and its in the direction to create these packages and assign classes to them. I am very new to this and still learning. So if I create a class and change where to assign it that should override it?

Comment: Yes, it knows where to correctly put the file for the package name you enter in the wizard.